# Italic Helvetica font in Beamer

Tags: beamer, italic, helvetica

How can an italic print of the font helvetica be achieved in the Beamer class?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting
\usepackage{fontspec} % load 'fontspec' when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

\usepackage{helvet}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textit{hello} \protect{\textit{hello}} hello 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

No matter what I do, the output is not italic. I have tried adding

```
\newcommand{\italnum}[1]{\begingroup\fontfamily{phv}\itshape#1\endgroup}
```

after the definition of the documentclass but this does not seem to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `helvet` provides other than a sans-serif family font? I always thought it did not.

Comment: Don't use helvet together with lualatex or xelatex.

Comment: Hey Ulrike. Is there any way to fix this that allows me to use both xelatex and helvet? I've tried using \usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} in combination with pdflatex instead and it works, but it completely changes the appearance of the font :/

Comment: @ilFuria: italic helvetica definitely works in the scrbook class (I believe all other classes as well) even in combination with xelatex, so I don't see why it shouldn't also work in beamer?

Comment: @Sebastian_92 I tried with the article class and pdfLaTeX, and only when I use sans serif the text gets printed in other than Computer Modern. Maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use helvet with xelatex and lualatex, use e.g. the tex gyre heros font:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel} % language listed last is default setting
\usepackage{fontspec} % load 'fontspec' when using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}

\usetheme{Berlin}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\textit{hello} \protect{\textit{hello}} hello
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I get an error saying the font cannot be found: ! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "TeX Gyre Heros" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.

Comment: Would you care to explain why helvetica can be used in combination with xelatex in the scrbook class, but not in beamer?? I don't really get why this is an issue.

Comment: helvet is not suited for xelatex, regardless of the class. I have no idea what you did in the scrbook document to get the impression that it works.  The tex gyre font should be part of every  current tex system, but perhaps you need to install it.